# Does WooCommerce 3.0 still able to display random products via recent_products shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I've been successfully using the following shortcode in WooCommerce 2.x to display 5 random products using the text widget:

```
[recent_products category="" per_page="5" columns="5" orderby="rand" order="asc"]
```

After upgrading WooCommerce to 3.0 I've noticed that it now outputs the same bunch of "random" products with every page refresh.

What can be wrong with the shortcode and is there a way to change random products shown by WooCommerce via **recent_products** shortcode every time the page loads?

*UPDATE:* Just noticed that now WooCommerce offers a different set of "random" products rather than those that were at the time of posting this question (3 hours ago).

Seems since version 3 WooCommerce's RNG uses hours instead of milliseconds as the seed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[recent_products category="" per_page="5" columns="5" orderby="rand" order="rand"]
```

Comment: I've tried that before posting this question. This way it just constantly outputs a different set of "random" items.

Comment: [recent_products category="" per_page="5" columns="5" orderby="rand" order="desc"]

Comment: then try this , in wooComm Docs they used Desc not asc

Comment: The same. Seems the problem hides in `rand`.